# How to bypass FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION validation rule in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation-rule

I am working on editing a record that would prevent a user from making changes in the page layout, they should use a button to make changes on a specific field. I created a new Validation Rule that would fire if the User(System Admin) tries to make changes on a specific field which is End Date on the page layout. I also have created an LWC quick action button that can be used to End Date the record, but I am getting a FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION saying that I have to use the quick action button even if I am using it and not making changes on the page layout. I imported the bypass all validation rule in the custom permission but still receiving the same error even if I am getting the right result of the custom permission. I have read one solution here saying that it is most likely to occur because the record that was being edited was already created before the new validation rule was added, so I created a new record but still getting the same error. Is there any way to work this out without using Apex if possible?
[image]

Comment: Additional info to the post, there are existing validation rule and I was able to catch it through conditions, the only problem is the recently created validation rule.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.